Hey! Welcome to new users, find us in chat if you have questions!
I've been seeing some new names popping up on answers. Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! Welcome back, if you're returning. :)
I've seen a few flags on obsolete comments, thanks for that as well.
If you need advice what to do about a post, e.g. 

what tags to put on them
whether to edit, flag or close,
or generally would like to chat with others on the Bitcoin.SE, 

feel free to join us in our chat room: mempool.
Cheers,
Murch
